# How to make the standard DP algorithm for 0/1 Knapsack make larger steps?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems

The [standard knapsack problem solution](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1) is O(nW) where we will increment the weight +1 at a time to get to the solution.

Is there any approach to the knapsack problem that does not require incrementing weight +1 at a time.

e.g. One way that I can think of is to divide all the numbers by its common

`Capacity = 100 weights = [5, 10, 20] -> Capacity = 20 weights = [1, 2, 4]`

Comment: Maybe you should look at computer science resources in stead of chunks of programming code. Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem) does a better job than that site.

Comment: By the way, if you link to a site with at least three algorithms and I don't know how many implementations, you should focus your reference.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong; the dynamic programming algorithm does *not* do that. It computes $m(n,W)$ according to the recurrence

$\qquad\displaystyle
  m(i,w) = \begin{cases}
    0, &i=0 \lor w=0; \\
    m(i-1,w), & w_i > w; \\
    \max \{ m(i-1,w), m(i-1, w - w_i) + v_i \}, &w_i \leq w .
  \end{cases}
$

Here, $(w_1, v_1), \dots, (w_n, v_n)$ are the weight-value pairs and $W$ is the knapsack size. Note how $m(i,w)$ is the maximum value that can be achieved with items $1, \dots, i$ and up to weight $w$; prove that by induction.

You can note two things:

1. The algorithm does not "move towards" $W$ in a straight fashion; it investigates many "paths" from $0$ to $W$ in an interleaved fashion, optimizing locally.
2. When it makes a stept, it does not have to be by $1$; all steps correspond to a $w_i$.